# DropZone acceptedFiles type filter

Tags: dropzone.js

I've got a [DropZone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone) form working perfectly with one exception, I can't seem to limit the file types as precisely as I need to.

Using `acceptedFiles: "image/*"` dims all folders and file types that are not images, as it should. *TIFF* is included though and I need to reduce it to exclusively *JPG* and *PNG*. A lot of trial and error has not gotten me there.

What I tried:

```
acceptedFiles: "image/jpg"
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png"
acceptedFiles: "image/jpg,png"
```

But they all make everything selectable.

What's the correct format for just *JPG* and *PNG*?

Comment: how you are passing the configuration to the dropzone?

Comment: acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.jpeg,.png" works for me

Answer (score 63, accepted):

More trial and error eventually turned up the solution:

```
Dropzone.options.dzone = {
acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
}
```

Apparently my error was primarily in using jpg which made it all fail. The above works like a charm.

Comment: No, this does not work. However, `acceptedFiles: ''` works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to hide unwanted file types from the context box as well. I had to add "acceptedMimeTypes", although in the docs it shows it as depreciated.

```
acceptFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/jpg',
acceptedMimeTypes: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/jpg',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Dropzone
   onDrop={this.handleFilesUpload}
   >
   {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
   <div {...getRootProps()}>
   <input
   {...getInputProps()}
   accept=".csv" /*you can use any file type */
   />
   <div className="drag-container">
      <img
         className="drag-img"
         src={Drag}
         alt="drag-img"
         />
      <p className="drag-container-para">Drop files here, or click to select files</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   )}
</Dropzone>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation along your code, and work on its formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate it from the controller as well.

```
$this->validate($request, [

        'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp']

    );
```