# Dropzone accepted Files not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I am working with dropzone to upload files. code is working fine but the `acceptedFiles` variable is not working in the script. the upload script is accepting all formats like .zip,.mp3 which should not be allowed. i have uploaded the `dropzone.js` file and see my code below :

**My upload script is here :**

```
 $(".dropzone2").dropzone({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>docupload',
        margin: 20,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        params:{
            'action': 'save',
            'projectId': '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2) ?>'

        },
        uploadOnDrop: true,
        uploadOnPreview: true,
        success: function(res, index){ console.log(index);
            $('#fileUpload').modal('hide');
        }
    });
```

**And the HTml calss is here :**

`<div class="dropzone2"></div>`

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: it is accepting all the files.

Comment: And that is bad because?

Comment: I have set some flags in my php function but i am not able to get them in success events.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28840773/50447

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually i found the issue.
The format which worked for me. `acceptedFiles:image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/jpg,application/pdf'`
. don't know why the `image/*` is not working as it was mentioned in the document. Thanks for all experts for their opinion.

Comment: It needs to be `acceptedFiles: ['image/*'].join(',')`

Answer (score 2):

you have to write the ending of the file format like:

```
acceptedFiles: '.png, .jpg'
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles) does state "The default implementation of accept checks the file's mime type or extension against this list. This is a comma separated list of mime types or file extensions. Eg.: image/*,application/pdf,.psd. If the Dropzone is clickable this option will be used as accept parameter on the hidden file input as well. "

Comment: @prakashtank maybe you have to work with the autoDiscover config

Comment: @prakashtank '.img' doesnt exist sorry that was my fault but i edited it and now it should be possible

Answer (score 0):

You have to change config of "/path/to/dropzone.js" file

you can change the config acceptedFiles: null to ..like

acceptedFiles: 'image/*',

Answer (score 0):

In dropzone.js, add defaultOptions to :

```
acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpg",
```

will not show unwanted file types when you browse for files.

I don't know why, but the configuration settings I made afterwards don't squash some settings like this one in defaultOptions. So I had to edit it in defaultOptions.

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
  url: null,
  method: "post",
  withCredentials: false,
  parallelUploads: 20,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  maxFilesize: 3, //mb
  paramName: "file",
  createImageThumbnails: true,
  maxThumbnailFilesize: 10, //mb
  thumbnailWidth: 100,
  thumbnailHeight: 100,
  filesizeBase: 1000,
  maxFiles: 20,
  params: {},
  clickable: true,
  ignoreHiddenFiles: true,
  acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpg",  //exactly this line
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  autoQueue: true,
  addRemoveLinks: true
}
```